# Detect the application is started by sync adapter

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am using android sync adapter. When the sync is started by the system, my application will be started, or the onCreate() method will be called.

In my application, I inherit the Application class and write some custom code in onCreate() function. If the sync adapter starts the app, I don't want these custom code to be executed however.

I wonder how I can detect if the application is started by sync adapter? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check the process name of your sync process in the manifest file (":sync" for my case)

```
    <service
        android:name=".sync.SyncService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:process=":sync">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
    </service>
```

You need a method to get the current process name

```
public String getCurrentProcessName(Context context) {
    // Log.d(TAG, "getCurrentProcessName");
    int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : manager.getRunningAppProcesses())
    {
        // Log.d(TAG, processInfo.processName);
        if (processInfo.pid == pid)
            return processInfo.processName;
    }
    return "";
}
```

Call the above code at Application.onCreate to detect if the current process is sync.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        String processName = Helper.getCurrentProcessName(this);
        if (processName.endsWith(":sync")) {
            Log.d(TAG, ":sync detected");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```